# Detect intersection without causing bodies to collide

Tags: cocos2d-x, chipmunk, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to detect the intersection of two objects (sprites) in my scene. I don't want the object geometric intersection to cause a collision between the bodies in the scene.

I've created PhysicalBody for both of my object shapes, but I can't find a way to detect the intersection without having both bodies hit each other on impact.

I'm using cocos2d-x 3+ with the default chipmunk engine (which I'd like to stick with for now)

The question is, how do I detect the intersection of elements without having them physically push each other when they intersect.

Comment: Well... I don't quite get your question. If two physic bodies intersect, they collide. I don't know about Chipmunk, but in Box2D you can make it so that a "collision" wouldn't cause a physics reaction, but rather send a signal, that these two bodies are touching. Would that be what you are looking for?

Comment: @Losiowaty yes, exactly that, I've been trying every setting I could think of but I cannot get that result

Comment: Well, I have no experience with chipmunk, so I cannot help you further - I added [tag:chipmunk] tag, so that people with more knowledge in it may find your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is very simple (Though it took me 2 days to figure it out)

When contact is detected and `onContactBegin()` is called, when the relevant shape is being hit returning `false` will stop the physical interaction.

Comment: It's even simpler than that; you set the *contact* bitmask but not the *collision* bitmask.